# How does induction fail in computable nonstandard models?

Tags: logic, nonstandard-models

[Tennenbaum's theorem](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TennenbaumTheorem.pdf) does not apply to [Robinson Arithmetic ($Q$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic#Metamathematics). There is a computable, nonstandard model of $Q$ "consisting of integer-coefficient polynomials with positive leading coefficient, plus the zero polynomial, with their usual arithmetic."

What is an example of how the [first order induction schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) fails in a computable, nonstandard model of $Q$? Can such a model have a predicate, in the language of Q, that is only true for standard natural numbers and false for "infinite" natural numbers? Can a computable nonstandard model have [overspill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overspill)?

Given the model above, what is an example of a statement, in the language of $Q$, that is true for the zero polynomial and all successors of the zero polynomial and false for some other polynomial in the model?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an even simpler one: "Every number is either even or odd." That is, $$\forall x\exists y(x=y+y \mbox{ or } x=y+y+1).$$ The polynomial $x$ is a counterexample.

---

Ignoring the specific model and focusing on the theory, it's also worth noting that Robinson arithmetic doesn't even prove that addition is commutative or that the successor of a number is different from that number! (If I recall correctly, this is covered in Burgess' book *Fixing Frege* - see a review at http://www.utexas.edu/cola/_files/iaa4774/On_Burgess_Fixing_Frege.pdf.)

EDIT: Now that I look more closely, this is basically all covered in the wikipedia page on Robinson arithmetic, in the section "Metamathematics"; I suggest you read it and the linked references.

FURTHER EDIT: Here's even more statements, with easy induction proofs, that Robinson doesn't believe! :P (Note that these *do* in fact hold in the specific model in the OP.)

- $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
- There are infinitely many primes. *More precisely, "for every $x$ there is a prime $>x$."*
- Unique factorization into primes.

See Francois Dorais' answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19857/has-decidability-got-something-to-do-with-primes.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth pointing out that "There are infinitely many primes" is formulated as "There is always a bigger prime", so when you say there are infinitely many primes can be false what you mean is that the set of primes is bounded.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's a good point - fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another example,
$$\forall x(S(x)\neq x)$$

It holds for $0$, and *if* it holds for $x$, then it holds for $S(x)$ as well. But it is possible to have a model with an element which is its own successor.

Comment: Note, however, that this doesn't provide an example for the specific model the OP mentions.

Comment: Sure, but also note that the question is *"What is an example of how the first order induction schema fails in a computable, nonstandard model of $Q$?"*, and there are many computable nonstandard models of Q.

Comment: Yes - I didn't want to give the impression that I thought this was a bad answer, I just wanted to clarify for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

For a sentence true for the ordinary natural numbers, but false in the polynomials described above, we can use
$$\forall w\exists y_1\exists y_2\exists y_3\exists y_4(w=y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2+y_4^2),$$
since by a result of Lagrange every non-negative integer is the sum of $4$ squares, but the polynomial $x$ is not a sum of $4$ squares of polynomials.